# Issue with derived column

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to split up a column and I want the value that comes after the comma.
Here are the column's values:

```
Managing Partner                                                       
Director, Enterprise Architect                                           
Manager, Storage Services
```

Not all values have a comma.

I'm using a derived column in SSIS and here is the code:

```
(LTRIM(SUBSTRING([Title ],FINDSTRING([Title ],",",1) + 1,LEN([Title ]))))
```

The issue I'm running into is the values that do not have a comma and I'm getting the whole string in my new column.

Comment: If there is no comma what is the expected output ? Also what is the source type of your data (you are getting data from a database, file ...?)

Comment: Beside the fact that I would suggest to use a transformation script task instead of a derived column, you could add a conditional check on the existence of `,` and writhe NULL to the column if no `,` is contained...

Answer (score 0):

If you query the data from a table, you could simply strip the string down to its parts via `LEFT` and `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT title
      ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',[title]) > 0 THEN LEFT(title,CHARINDEX(',',[title])-1) ELSE title END AS Title_Left
      ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',[title]) > 0 THEN RIGHT(title,len(title)-CHARINDEX(',',[title])) END AS Title_Right
  FROM test
```

see fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b1dfa/1/1

If you need to handly another input such as a flat file or similar, you can add the corresponding handling to the derived column (if string contains no comma, output the whole string as column 1, other wise the left characters before the comma; similar with the right part: if no comme is included, leave the column empty otherwise output the right part of the string from just after teh comma to the end of the string.